# ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [400] Invalid character in filename: flask/ext/setuptools/script (dev).tmpl

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gcloud

I am trying to launch my app into app engine using the following command.

```
gcloud --project=xxx preview app deploy app.yaml
```

I am then given the following error message

```
Updating module [default]...|
Updating module [default].../
Updating module [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [400] Invalid character in filename: server/lib/flask/ext/setuptools/script (dev).tmpl
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Contents of Script (dev).tmpl

```
# EASY-INSTALL-DEV-SCRIPT: %(spec)r,%(script_name)r
__requires__ = %(spec)r
__import__('pkg_resources').require(%(spec)r)
__file__ = %(dev_path)r
exec(compile(open(__file__).read(), __file__, 'exec'))
```

**Questions**

1. What is Script (dev).tmpl
2. Why am I getting this error.

---

updated based on the first response

I have added the following to app.yaml file.

skip_files:
- server/lib/flask/ext/setuptools/script (dev).tmpl

However, it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 2):

So the skip_files works you must antislash the special characters.
Add this to your app.yaml

```
skip_files:
 - server/lib/flask/ext/setuptools/script\ \(dev\).tmpl
```

set your relative path according to your .yaml

Answer (score 1):

1. `script (dev).tmpl` is a [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)-related file. Not terribly important for you to worry about as a Flask user.
2. This error is related to a bug in `gcloud`. The next `gcloud` release (92.0.0) will fix it. In the mean time, you can work around by [adding this file to the `skip_files` section in your `app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Skipping_files).

Comment: Did you upgrade to gcloud 92.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is several months later, but I just set up a Google App Engine account and downloaded the SDK last week. I'm using the most recent Flask skeleton for GAE apps, and I was getting the same error about `script (dev).tmpl`. (The file is just in a different directory.)

I tried using `skip_file`, too, and it didn't work for me either. I looked up the [documentation about skipping files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Skipping_files), and I don't think it's meant for what we tried to use it for. I deleted it, and my little Hello World test deployed with no further errors. Hopefully when I build something more complex I won't run into any errors...